# Fuseki s-query Query cancelled

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki, apache-jena, turtle-rdf

I have a Fuseki server running on localhost with a large enough dataset, about 7 million triples (the loaded file was N3 @ 370mb).

I've been trying to get back as much data in a query as I can but I've been having trouble with timeouts. I'm just running a simple query to get everything with a limit that I've been changing upwards until I get a query that won't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM <myGraph>
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o
}
LIMIT 200000
```

The interesting thing about this query is that it works on the provided web server interface `localhost:3030` (albeit with a bit of work on firefox's part) but doesn't work when run via the command line

`./s-query --service=http://localhost:3030/dataset/query --query=queryFile.rq`

The error I get is:

```
##  Query cancelled due to timeout during execution   ##
##  ****          Incomplete results           ****   ##
```

and on Fuseki logs (with dates and times replaced):

```
[date time] Fuseki     INFO  [5] exec/select
[date time] Fuseki     INFO  [5] Query Cancelled - results truncated (but 200 already sent)
[date time] Fuseki     INFO  [5] 200 OK (11.370 s)
```

Also, I should mention that it's not always 11s. Sometimes it's more, sometimes it's less. But it's (as far as I've seen, always within a second or two of this).

I've tried modifying the s-query file to change `http.read_timeout` in `response_no_body()` and `response_print_body()`. But it doesn't change anything.

I've also tried adding the line `ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "30000" ] ;` to `config.ttl` as it suggests but, again, it doesn't seem to change anything.

Contents of the "config.ttl" file in /run/

```
# Licensed under the terms of http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

## Fuseki Server configuration file.

@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;

# Example::
# Server-wide query timeout.   
# 
# Timeout - server-wide default: milliseconds.
# Format 1: "1000" -- 1 second timeout
# Format 2: "10000,60000" -- 10s timeout to first result, 
#                            then 60s timeout for the rest of query.
#
# See javadoc for ARQ.queryTimeout for details.
# This can also be set on a per dataset basis in the dataset assembler.
#
# ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "30000" ] ;

# Add any custom classes you want to load.
# Must have a "public static void init()" method.
# ja:loadClass "your.code.Class" ;   

# End triples.
.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Fuseki Version: 2.0.0

Comment: Which version?  By default, there is no timeout but theer are various way sto set it, including as the server starts. Is the database a TDB database? If not, the FROM will have an effect.

Comment: oh, sorry I forgot to include this. I'm using Fuseki 2.
I'm not sure whether I'm using a TDB database or not, to be honest, how might I check?

Comment: How are you running the server? Someone created /dataset either via a config file or the UI.  Fuseki2 has a bug in processing arq:queryTimeout in the timeout (fixed in the development snapshot) but it will not cause a 12s timeout; it would force a 3 s timeout.  What does your config file look like?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I created it via the UI. I just entered the dataset name and then set it as "persistent".   
I then put the data on it via the s-put script.

Comment: I added the config file to my original post by the way. I have nothing in /run/configuration/

Comment: There is stil nothing to indicate a 11.370s timeout and it does work when given at the console.11.370s is a rather odd number.  Is there anything in /etc/default/fuseki.ttl? How are you running the server?

Comment: I run the server from the command line. 

    ./fuseki-server 

There is no fuseki file in /etc/default/

Comment: Also, I should mention that it's not always 11s. Sometimes it's more, sometimes it's less. But it's (as far as I've seen, always within a second or two of this).